# Mean of the product of a signal with its conjugate

Tags: signal-analysis, beamforming

I have to find $E\{s_m\cdot s_n^*\}$, where $E$ denotes mean or expected value; $s$ is a signal at $m \in [1\ldots M]$ elements and $^*$ denotes its conjugate. I am doing it by dividing it into two parts, i.e first finding $E\{s_m\cdot s_n^*\}$ for say $m=n$ and then finding $E\{s_m\cdot s_n^*\}$ for $m\ne n$.

My question is do I need to simply add the values obtained by computing $E\{s_m\cdot s_n^*\}$ for say $m=n$ and $E\{s_m\cdot s_n^*\}$ for $m \ne n$ in order to get the value of $E\{s_m\cdot s_n^*\}$? Would it be correct to add in this way?

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: "mean" and "expected" are two quite different concepts; it's totally ok to interchange the terms $\mathit{iff}$ you know what you're doing, but you should totally be clear on the difference between the expectation of a random variable and the mean value of an observation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller How is $E[x]$ different from the mean of $x$ ? ;-)

Comment: @PeterK. always, unless you're a) *particularly lucky* or b) have an infinite length of observation of $x$!

Comment: Are you conflating the ensemble average with the mean?

Comment: /me *looks up "conflate"*  then: /me agrees with @PeterK. ; That might actually be a mistake on my side (English not being the language I was educated in), but I'd say *mean* applies to something that you can *actually observe* and *expectation* to an inherent quality of an RV.

Comment: @zhsa:  You appear to be asking your question in a mathematical way, but then asking how it's computed.  As Marcus says, the two are very different.  It seems to me that $E\{s_m \cdot s_n^*\}$ could give you a matrix of values indexed by $n$ and $m$.  Can you give us more detail about what $s_m$ is and what you're doing to try to compute it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Fair enough!  I'm just splitting hairs, hence the ";-)" in my original comment.  Yes, I agree with you: you have to be careful with what is meant by "mean" vs "expectation". Sorry to be overly pedantic.

Comment: @zhsa: what Peter said. Also, could you clearly describe what you think should be the result of your calculations? As it looks to me, $E[s_m s^*_n]$ is a $m\times m$ matrix.

Comment: @PeterK. don't apologize! I started the hair-splitting. Point is that I hope OP sees the need for mathematical *exactness* here; the sum of all crosscorrelation coefficients is surely something different than the covariance matrix than an *estimate* of the covariance matrix based on observation of a single realisation of a $m$-dimensional stochastic process.

Comment: @zhsa: also, you say "$s$ *is a signal*", but it would be better if you mathematically defined it like a function or random variable, eg.: *$s$ is a signal, $s \in \mathbb R \rightarrow {\mathbb C}^m$*. Or is each realization of $s$ really just a vector in $\mathbb C^m$?

Comment: @all s summation of signals at 12 different elements(say antennas) and is given by summation of signals at each different elements plus noise at each element. I need to find out the power of s, which in DSP is computed by E[s.conj(s)]. Since I have m different elements, I am first computing E[s.conj(s)] for s at any element m and s at any element n for m equals n; and E[s.conj(s)] for s at any element m and s at any element n for m not equals n; and then adding the two results obtained from these two cases.

Comment: I want to know that is simply adding the two results the correct way of computing E[s.conj(s)] of a set of elements?